# error when trying to save geojson object using mongoosejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

If I have the following schema:

```
var zipSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  zc_code             : String,
  zc_population       : Number,
  zc_households       : Number,
  zc_housevalue       : Number,
  zc_householdincome  : Number,
  zc_statecode        : String,
  zc_state            : String,
  zc_city             : String,
  zc_cityname         : String,
  modified_at         : Date, 
  center: {
    type: {type: String},
    coordinates: []
  }
})
zipSchema.index({ center: '2dsphere' });
```

And the I try this:

```
    var zipInfo = {
      zc_code: '78746',
      zc_population: 26928,
      zc_households: 10839,
      zc_housevalue: 344000,
      zc_householdincome: 100571,
      zc_latitude: '30.295657',
      zc_long: '-97.813727',
      zc_statecode: 'TX',
      zc_state: 'Texas',
      zc_city: 'AUSTIN',
      center: {
        coordinates: [-73.7567, 42.6525],
        type: 'Point'
      }
    }

    Zip.create(zipInfo, function(err) { if (err) console.log(err) })
```

I get this error every time:

MongoError: location object expected, location array not in correct format

What am I missing.  I have searched stackoverflow and seen several different setups for the geojson stuff.  I even tried directly copying some stuff from mongoosejs tests and still get errors.  I am at a dead end.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I haven't done it myself so this is a guess, but shouldn't it be `center: { coordinates: [Number], type: String, index: '2dsphere' }`?

Comment: Why is it center: {
    type: {type: String},
    coordinates: []
  } and not simply center: {
    type: String,
    coordinates: []
  }?

Comment: Josh, I don't know.  I've tried many different combinations and none have worked.  I have tried the way you suggested.

Comment: @kidbrax did you try my solution? Regardless of solution you probably have to run `db.collectionName.dropIndexes()` in mongo first.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to move on and had already changed my schema to use plain 2d indexes and it worked.  I'm going to leave it that way for now. I had tried dropping the indexes though.  I think it might have been as Kay suggested and there was an existing invalid document.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work for me either but I have just fixed it by naming the geometry field: "loc" like here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/

Here the example I used:

```
var cableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    reference: String,
    owner: String,
    status: String,
    setup: String,
    model: Number,
    loc: {
        type: {type:String},
        coordinates: Array
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following with the latest mongoose and it did work for me. Which version are you using?  And as for the { type: {type: String } } question, I believe it is because type is also a mongoose keyword type:

```
var zipSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  zc_code             : String,
  zc_population       : Number,
  zc_households       : Number,
  zc_housevalue       : Number,
  zc_householdincome  : Number,
  zc_statecode        : String,
  zc_state            : String,
  zc_city             : String,
  zc_cityname         : String,
  modified_at         : Date, 
  center: {
    type: {type:String},
    coordinates: [Number]
  }
})

zipSchema.index({ center: '2dsphere' });

var zipInfo = {
      zc_code: '78746',
      zc_population: 26928,
      zc_households: 10839,
      zc_housevalue: 344000,
      zc_householdincome: 100571,
      zc_latitude: '30.295657',
      zc_long: '-97.813727',
      zc_statecode: 'TX',
      zc_state: 'Texas',
      zc_city: 'AUSTIN',
      center: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [-73.7567, 42.6525]
      }
    }

var Zip = mongoose.model('Zip', zipSchema);

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  Zip.create(zipInfo, function(err) { 
      if (err) console.log(err);

      mongoose.disconnect();

   })
});
```

The result was:

```
> db.zips.find().pretty()
{
    "zc_code" : "78746",
    "zc_population" : 26928,
    "zc_households" : 10839,
    "zc_housevalue" : 344000,
    "zc_householdincome" : 100571,
    "zc_statecode" : "TX",
    "zc_state" : "Texas",
    "zc_city" : "AUSTIN",
    "_id" : ObjectId("522e2df92aacd22e89000001"),
    "center" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -73.7567,
            42.6525
        ]
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
> db.zips.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "test.zips",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "center" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "ns" : "test.zips",
        "name" : "center_2dsphere",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    }
]
>
```

Comment: I'm using mongoose 3.6.19 and I tried exactly what you have and am still getting errors.  I'm using mongo 2.4.4

Comment: Also, could you do db.zips.find() for me?  It might be that you might have a document in the collection already that contains a center field that is not in the correct format.